# О падежах в некоторых предикатах

Tags: синтаксис

Даны предикаты:

(1)  "Мама мыть окно в [момент времени] t.",

(2)  "Окно мыть в [момент времени] t.".

В каких падежах указаны существительные "мама" и "окно" в предикатах (1) и (2)?

Примечание: Предполагаю, что в предикатах (1) и (2) "мама" и "окно" указаны в именительном падеже (номинативе).

Answer (score 1):

(1) "Мама мыть окно в [момент времени] t." Мама-субъект - им.пад.(кто?что?),окно-объект-вин.пад.(кого?что?)

2) "Окно мыть в [момент времени] t.".Окно моют, окно мыли, окно будут мыть. Окно- объект действия какого-то субъекта, значит, вин.пад.

Comment: 1. Большое спасибо.

2. Если у Вас будет время, скажите какой следующий падеж (после именительного и винительного) следует преподать ребёнку?

Comment: Тогда уж по порядку, родительный:

Вот инструкция 
 http://www.kakprosto.ru/kak-26362-kak-razlichit-roditelnyy-i-vinitelnyy-padezhi#ixzz2sqC3HTIK

Comment: Большое спасибо.